# widgets with cutomized service?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, app-widgets, customization

I am new to `android`, just bought a `nexus 5`. 
I am now trying to customize my desktop (I am using [nova launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher) + [Zooper free widget maker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.zooper.zwfree) ).

Now, the problem is, can I customize the service of a `widget`? Say, I liked a weather widget in `zooper`, I want to use it. But the weather service of my choice is accuweather(no business, just an example). 
How can I have these two together?

Comment: I don't know what options Zooper has, but if it doesn't offer the feature you want, you'll have to use a different widget.

Comment: Try Dashclock which has alternatives weather widgets and more...

Answer (score 0):

The general answer I'm afraid is "you usually can't". In principle there's nothing to stop a developer from writing a widget that supports multiple information sources, and allowing you to choose between them. In practice, though, that's often just more trouble than it's worth, as those different sources may deliver their data in quite different formats that the code would have to handle.